# how to call python function in c extern cython?

Tags: cython

Basically I have a cython program as below, and I want to call the `pyfunction` in my c extern code:

file.pyx:

```
cdef extern from *:
    r"""
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
       pyfunction("what do you want?");

       return 0
    }
    """

cdef int pyfunction(str):
     print(str)
```

The documentation, I read was to use `#include "python_module.h"` but in my case, both c extern and python code is within the same pyx module.

Can someone help on how to call `pyfunction` in my main c function?

Comment: It is unclear, what you try to achieve.  Should it become a C-extension? In this case `main()` (I would rather call it differently something like `mymain`) should be used/callable from python. If it should become embedded Python, you need to initialize the Python-interpreter before you can call  its functionality in your `main`-function.

Answer (score -1):

As explained here: https://neehack.com/article?post=O8SIYC96DH

I simply had to reference my python function at the end of my `c` code as following:

```
cdef extern from *:
    r"""
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
       pyfunction("what do you want?");

       return 0
    }
    """
    int pyfunction(char *str)

cdef int pyfunction(char *str):
    print(str)
```

Comment: I don't know, what you do with this code, but the result won't be something usable: if it should become an embedded python, the executable will not link. If it should become a C-extension, it will not link on Windows or won't get loaded on Linux.

Comment: Given the high probability, that you are the author of the link you have provided: you should disclose your involvement, otherwise the whole Q&A comes over like spam.